# Using OpenGL Compatibility Profile with Intel HD GPU + Mesa

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, gpu, fragment-shader

I was given an OpenGL application written by another team and I've been struggling to get it to work for nearly a week now. My set-up has a core profile of 3.3 (GLSL 3.3, Mesa 11.2)and compatibility profile of 3.0 (GLSL 1.3, Mesa 11.2). I tried running some test applications using the core profile on my set up and was successful. However, I know for a fact that this application uses the 3.0 compatibility profile (uses ARB functions in the glext.h) but it keeps throwing INVALID_OPERATION errors (1282) whenever functions like glUseProgramObjectARB, glActiveTextureARB, glUniform1iARB get executed.

Any help in solving this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: So you set a compatibility profile, right. But want to use some glxxxARB functions. The first step is finding if those ARB funcs are supported by your GPU. `glxinfo` gives you useful info.

Comment: Is Mesa actually claiming to support [`ARB_shader_objects`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_objects.txt) in either context?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "3.0 compatibility profile", and mesa doesn't support compatibility profiles at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and compatibility profile of 3.0 (GLSL 1.3, Mesa 11.2)

Certainly not. Support for Compatibility Profiles is optional. So far only the proprietary drivers of NVidia and AMD do support them at all. All the other OpenGL implementations don't.

> However, I know for a fact that this application uses the 3.0 compatibility profile (uses ARB functions in the glext.h)

Those likely are *not* compatibility profile functions. More likely those are meant used with a OpenGL-2.1 context. In fact much of OpenGL-3 before core profiles were introduced behaves more or less like 2.1 + some extensions (although the use of `glUseProgramObjectARB` doesn't fit that pattern).

My suggestion: Try to get out of that tarpit that are programs aimed at compatibility profiles; it's just too much technical debt in the long run. If you absolutely must support earlier versions (i.e. 2.1, which is supported practically everywhere now) cover that by a different codepath.